# Pairing issue when using SingleEntry (Android)

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, socketscan

Socket Mobile SDK documentation states that the socket mobile scanner must be in "SPP" mode in order to work with the SingleEntry example. However, it seems that none of the Android phones i've tested recognize the device when in this mode for initial pairing. It does display in the paired devices list, connects to it fine, but does not fire any of the events (OnDeviceArrival, OnDecodedData, etc..) when a scan happens.

I can only get the SingleEntry example app to work with my Socket Mobile S800 by following the below steps (exactly):

1. Make sure scanner is in HID mode (default)
2. On my Android device, scan for pair-able devices. (the S800 displays with a keyboard icon)
3. Select the S800 device. (S800 does beep confirmation on connection)
4. Once the device is paired, un-pair it.
5. Change the S800 mode to "SPP" by scanning the appropriate code (recommended mode to work with Xamarin SingleEntry example)
6. Re-pair with the S800 device on my Android phone. (the S800 icon is now a desktop instead of a keyboard)
7. Open the "Socket EZ Pair" app, select pair using Bluetooth, select my S800 device from the list.
8. Now the OnDecodedData callback fires in the SingleEntry project.

What is the "Socket EZ Pair" app doing that i should be doing in my code to properly pair the device when in "SPP" mode?

Are there any better solutions for cross platform Bluetooth scanning? I'm particularly interested in just the OnScan (OnDecodedData) events...

Comment: Are you using the unmodified SingleEntry Xamarin.Android application? What is your target framework/SDK?

Comment: Yes, unmodified example. Target is Marshmallow (6.0) and min target is set to 4.0.3 (API 15)

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

The explanation is actually very simple. The SingleEntry Xamarin.Android app doesn't handle configuring the scanner for ScanAPI.

As you noted, after pairing the scanner you need to use EZ Pair before the scanner will be recognized by your app. This is because when you pair the scanner using Bluetooth settings, it creates an *outgoing* connection to the scanner, but ScanAPI listens for *incoming* connections. EZ Pair presents you with a list of paired Bluetooth devices, it connects to the one you select and configures that scanner to connect back before closing the connection.

The [SingleEntry Android](https://github.com/SocketMobile/samples-android/tree/master/singleEntry) sample application includes the EZ Pair logic, but the Xamarin sample does not.

However, once you've used EZ Pair to configure your scanner to connect back, you should receive device arrival and decoded data notifications in the unmodified SingleEntry Xamarin.Android sample application.

#### Original answer

**Not the solution, but good to check**

Runtime permissions were introduced in Android 6.0 and SingleEntry has not been updated to check for the required permissions. Unfortunately, the file that sets the target framework is not checked in to git so fresh clones of the sample app now target newer versions than SingleEntry was designed for.

If you open Settings > Apps > Single Entry > Permissions and enable the storage permission, then it should start working.

The real fix is to check for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `BLUETOOTH` permissions before calling `ScanApiHelper.Open()` in your application.

Comment: I'm using the Visual Studio example, it already had BLUETOOTH checked in the permissions. I added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and still have no luck with the events firing. I un-paired, re-paired and started the process from scratch. When i use the "Socket EZ Pair" app to pair it is the only time i hear the confirmation beeps from the scanner device. i never get those alerts when attempting to connect using Androids native BT pairing app... any other things i could try?

Comment: Enabling these permissions in Visual Studio adds them to your AndroidManifest, but Android 23+ requires you to request permissions at runtime - in addition to putting them in your manifest. You should be performing the steps to enable the storage permission for the unmodified SingleEntry app on your Android device. If you check for the permission in your application before opening ScanAPI, you don't need to perform this manual step

Comment: I have verified via calling "ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission()" that i do have both the required permissions. I believe the underlying issue is in the paring of the S800 device to my phone. When pairing via HID mode the device has beep confirmation once connected. When in SPP mode, there is no beep confirmation once connected. the only way i get the beep confirmation is if once paired with my phone i open the "Socket EZ Pair" app then select the S800 from the app's list. It then pairs my phone with a series of confirmation beeps that don't sound when trying to pair it "normally".

Comment: I believe this issue could be related to the ScanAPI documentation "8.6
Socket EZ Pair feature". Is there a code example to do this before i call "Open()"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've updated the answer with an explanation of EZ Pair. The 2D scanners can be put in SPP mode and configured to connect back using a single barcode, but the Bluetooth pairing method is the only method that works for all scanners

Comment: I have implemented PostSetProfileConfigDevice() and PostSetDisconnectDevice() in C# using the "SingleEntry Android" Java example as advised. There seems to still be a piece of the puzzle missing... Both these calls require the first parameter of DeviceInfo. The problem is there is no device object because it has not been properly paired yet. How is the "Socket EZ Pair" app pairing the scanner to the device before these 2 methods are called to correct the scanner's stream to receive incoming connections?

Comment: Anyone having the SingleEntry Xamarin Android example with the EZ pair logic implemented they want to share?